# load a project outside application folder in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Good day everyone!

I have a problem of loading a project outside my application folder and I got this error if I tried to browse my other page which is not a CI project.

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI' not found in /home/gcceclc/public_html/application/third_party/MX/Modules.php on line 91
```

outside the application folder, I have another folder that consist of my other page

```
home/gcceclc/public_html/other_project_folder_without_ci
```

I'm thinking of something like I have a problem with my .htaccess because before I over write my .htaccess I was able to browse my other project.

Please if someone knows how to solve this, please share. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is the solution that solve my problem

```
RewriteBase //
```

as I thought it's my .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the location of the application directory in the main index.php file?

```
$application_folder = 'application';
```

Change it to

```
$application_folder = '../application';
```

Comment: where exactly I can see that? sorry I'm new with codeigniter

Comment: In the index.php file, within the main directory.